# Importing a projector to the US from Germany

Tags: usa, europe, import-taxes

I have a projector in Germany that I bought for a modest price and I want to ask my friend to bring it to US (where I currently live). I was wondering will he end up paying import taxes? And is there anyway to avoid such a payment.

The projector is used (actually I bought a second-hand one from ebay), and I imagine for that reason it should be exempted from import tax, but I would appreciate to get some guidance from the people who are more familiar with the issue.

Comment: There is no reason that second-hand stuff *should* be exempted from any tax and it's not generally the case. However, you typically have to pay duties and taxes on the current value of the goods you are importing so if you can prove it's not worth much/how much you paid for it, you might be able to reduce the amount due and/or [include the projector into the regular traveller allowance](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/454/~/duty-free-exemption,-gifts).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I think I'd better sell it on eBay in Germany then. Well I haven't paid taxes when I was buying the second hand one and that was the reason that I thought maybe it would be the case.

Comment: You don't pay VAT on a transaction between private persons within the EU because it has been paid the first time the goods were sold/imported. But that's precisely why you need to pay it when you import something, even if you purchased it second-hand or owned it for a long time. The US has no generic federal VAT or sales tax but duties apply.

Comment: Duty on a projector appears to be zero or at most 5%. I don't really know how to read the table. You might also, in theory, owe sales tax to the state.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, thanks a lot for your reply. Can you tell me where did you find the table? You mean to owe it and not to pay it now? Well the problem is my friend is bringing it in so he has to pay it, and I cannot take the charge....since I am already here in the US

Comment: http://hts.usitc.gov/?query=projector Look at section 8528. What I mean is that if your friend pays the duty, it looks like you owe him a bottle of decent wine. 5% tops, in some cases 0, and that would be on the depreciated value of used equipment. Note, I'm not a lawyer and I've never done this. But if you really want this projector maybe see if US Customs can give you a definitive answer by email or phone.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, thanks a lot man! Of course I am not gonna come and blame you :) .... but I really appreciate your information. I will either check it out as you suggest or just sell it on ebay and buy a different one here!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: did you check that the projector works fine with with the 110V power in the US and does not need 230V, as provided in Europe? If the projector really needs 230V, then it's probably not worth the hassle (as a power transformer would be needed to operate it in the US).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in theory there may be some sort of a tax levied on a used projector, *in practice* nobody is going to care about it even if the customs inspector stops your friend. A single used projector is simply too low of a value for the inspection to bother.

If you want to be on the safe side, have your friend declare it. At the very most he will have to pay [5% of the value](https://hts.usitc.gov/?query=projector), which shouldn't be more than $50 for a used item.